# SwiftUI TextField is always deleting itself

Tags: swiftui, textfield, macos-ventura

After updating to macOS Ventura 13.0, when i use the get: set: method inside a `TextField`, it now prevents me from typing in the `TextField`. This wasn't an issue before.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State var testing1 = ""
    @State var testing2 = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            TextField("Enter Text", text: Binding<String>(
        
                get: { testing1 },
                set: { testing2 = ($0)}))

        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

I've tested with my other apps and the same thing is happening. Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your `testing2` to the value that you're entering into your `TextField`, but in your binding, you're using `testing1` as the value you're getting, with these combined, your `testing1` is always empty because you're not assigning it to anything in anywhere. consider replacing your `Binding` with either this:

```swift
TextField("Enter Text", text: Binding<String>(
    
            get: { testing1 },
            set: { testing1 = ($0)})
)
```

or this

```swift
TextField("Enter Text", text: Binding<String>(
            get: { testing2 },
            set: { testing2 = ($0)})
)
```